# WCF protobuf-net with streamed transfer mode works worse than with buffered

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, protobuf-net

I am analyzing performance of our company's WCF services a whole week. The main task for me is compare the transfer modes: **buffered** and **streamed**. On some services we use standart contracts with messages and protobuf-net in endpoint behavior, and on some another we don't use any third-party and use WCF out of box. For my tests I am using a profiler and analyzing call trees with memory allocation. I have found out that with a stardard encoder streamed transfer mode works better than buffered, in my case 2000 Mb vs 400 Mb per test. But with protobuf-net I have found out that streamed mode works worse than buffered. In this case memory allocations for the both modes are equal, but performance (time) in streamed mode was down from 140 s to 250 s per test.

Because of what is going on?

**UPD:**
Test is simple. Run your standard WCF service and set protobuf endpoint behavior with buffered (default) transfer mode and request many times the results which contains many items for serialization. Your memory allocation will be X, time is Y. Then run your test on streamed transfer mode. Your memory allocation will be same, but time is Y*1,75.
I use dotTrace timeline for profiling.

Comment: Post your test code, I suspect that your perf code is broken. Streamed mode should use less memory.

Comment: It is true, streamed mode uses less memory indeed. But without protobuf-net. And the other cases: **protobuf-net + buffered** mode uses same memory like **protobuf-net + streamed** mode, only perf looks worse approximately than 75% on streamed mode.